# Servlet/JSP: Property 'id' not found on type mobile

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

1) I have a link in an HTML page which simulates an HTTP `GET` request.(by manually supplying the query string. This page basically calls a Servlet where a database access is done in its `doGet()` method. The SQL query is sent as part of the query string.

`http://localhost:8080/prelim_db_test_19_3_2013/md?q=select * from test.mobile`
(`test` is the MySQL DB and `mobile` is the table).

2) Then, the results are stored in an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList <mobile> mylist=new ArrayList<mobile> ();
mylist.add(new mobile(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("name")));
```

where `mobile` is simply a class with `id` and `name` as class variables (and a constructor as well)

3) The `ArrayList` is then forwarded to another JSP as:

```
request.setAttribute("answer", mylist);
request.getRequestDispatcher("info.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

4) Now in the second JSP, I simple use `<c:forEach>` to iterate and print the table contents:

```
<c:forEach items="${answer}" var="i">
    <tr>
        <td>${i.id}</td>
        <td>${i.name}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Yet, when I run the project, an exception is thrown:

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'id' not found on type mobile`

at this line:

`request.getRequestDispatcher("info.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Note that the DB access itself works fine when the results are printed to console(so the Servlet gets called too with my query string). Here's my project setup in Eclipse(if there's any problem with the way it's set up):

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT** `mobile.java`:

```
public class mobile {
 int id;
 String name;
public mobile(int i,String n) {
    id=i;
    name=n;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mobile class you need to put setter and getters for the fields.Then only you can access in jsp.I think you did not kept setter and getters for them.

Comment: Well, shouldn't the class constructor be enough? I've defined a constructor that takes (int,String) so that `ArrayList.add()` would use that constructor.

Comment: can u define getter methods and setter methods once.I think we need to put these only.But i am not sure

Comment: Thanks a lot! My initial setters had a typo! Wish I could accept both answers!

Answer (score 0):

As @PSR and @CaptainGouLash pointed out correctly, getters and setters need to set up so that the class variables can be accessed via JSTL.

See:
[this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html) in addition to [this as pointed out by @CaptainGouLash](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)